# How to pass String[] to method accepting String in JAVA

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java, want to understand how to pass a "String array" to a method which accepts "String". Do I need to convert "String array" to "String"

As shown below in method I am passing string "abcd" to method "takeParam". There i want to pass static "String[]" like below

```
String[] abcd = {"aa","bb"};
```

How to do that :

```
private void Apps() {

        try {
            takeParam(abcd);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your method does not accept String. you have no parameters defined.

Comment: Yes, I want to define array "packageName" and pass that to method "addDisallowedApplication" method. How can I do that?

Comment: If a method accepts a string then the method is, usually, internally wired to work with that particular parameter type. At the very most, what you can do is to iterate over the elements within your array and construct a string by concatenating your elements. However, without seeing the internals of `addDisallowedApplication` we can only speculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a `String[]` to a function parameter which is a `String`.

You can either:

Send a particular `String` from your `String[]` array using it's `index` and looping it.

```
String[] packageName = {"com.abc.abc","com.def.def"};
for(int i = 0; i < packageName.length; i++)
{
   try 
   {
      addDisallowedApplication(packageName[i]);
   } 
   catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Or Change your method description to accept a `String[]`.

```
public void addDisallowedApplication(String[] array)
```

Comment: Thanks @Uma. That helped

Comment: Please don't downvote unless you verify the answer. Thanks @Uma

Answer (score 0):

start the method name lower case please.

```
private void addDisallowedApplication(String[] pAllPackage) {
```

or

```
private void addDisallowedApplication(List<String> pAllPackage) {
```

pass the values like this:

```
List<String> lAllPackage = new ArrayList<>();
lAllPackage.add(a);
lAllPackage.add(b);
addDisallowedApplication(lAllPackage)
```

or (if you want to do it with String array)

```
String[] lAllPackage = {a,b};
addDisallowedApplication(lAllPackage)
```

and please dont forgett to change the parameter type of `addDisallowedApplication` to `String[]` or `List<String>`

**UPDATE**

```
List<String> lAllPackage = new ArrayList<>();
for (PackageInfo pi : list) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Iterate package list");
        lAllPackage.add(pi.packageName);
}
try {
   addDisallowedApplication(lAllPackage);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Nop Stefan. Both approach wouldn't work. I tried it, It will say "The method addDisallowedApplication(String) is not applicable for the arguments (String[])"

Comment: of course you have to change the parameter type inside the method header of addDisallowedApplication. If that is not possible you cannot pass a String[] or List<String>.

Comment: Yes, check my edited question, have edited code and tried but that won't work. I guess i will have to use for loop. Any idea?

Comment: see my updated answer. I suggest you to use List<String> instead of String[]. Furthermore add  the code of addDisallowedApplication to you question.

Comment: Sorry @Stefan. Not sure who downvoted. Your input was also useful. I upvoted it again. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass some params to method you must do it like this:

```
methodName(ArgumentType argument);
```

so, for your case it will be:

```
//call your method:
{
    ...
    String[] a = new String[]();
    Apps(a);
}

private void Apps(String[] paramName) {
    //do something with String array paramName[]
}
```

Comment: the method is addDisallowedApplication not App.

Comment: Sorry @Stefan. Not sure who downvoted. Your input was also useful. I upvoted it again. Thanks for helping